# Unable to parse Json data ---- student data(Key) and data(Key) in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm unable to parse this data using javascript, I want studentdata and question data dynamically ...

**CODE:**

```
{
    "studentdata": "[{\"studentid\":3,\"attemptid\":\"724\",\"tokenid\":\"dc049c8429af5ec2b8e7fe8a0b20d4a3\"}]",
    "quizid": "5",
    "tap": false,
    "body": "",
    "data": "[{\"question\":\"If a and b are negative numbers, and b - a is negative\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]},{\"question\":\"The equation 2x 7 \u003d 2(x 5) has one solution\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[false,true]},{\"question\":\"If f(x)\u003dsqrt(1-x), then f(-3)\u003d2\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]},{\"question\":\"The reciprocal of 0 is equal to 0\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[false,true]},{\"question\":\"The additive inverse of -10 is equal to 10\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]}]",
    "title": "Quiz"
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks -

Comment: That's not a code. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: post what you tried?

Comment: @HarishSoni You got any soln?

Comment: Please post what you tried to achieve the result

Comment: @HarishSoni I tried to parse studentdata values and data values using JS code, i am getting error

Comment: use  `toString()` on response, and then `JSON.parse($RESULT)`

Comment: @crazy_ljuba   $RESULT ?? It is not PHP

Comment: @KumarK well, you can use in javascript the variable as well as that.. this was just to state, that it was a variable (easier hm?). Nevertheless, JS can parse the JSON with that function.

Comment: @crazy_ljuba Sorry, Its throwing error:        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 20
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: `var response = { that_json_there }.toString(); `
`console.log( JSON.parse(response) ); `

If that doesn't work 

`var result = JSON.stringify ( that_json_there ) ;`
`console.log( JSON.parse ( result ); `

Comment: You can always test the JSON code inside the `Console` of the browser that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
    "studentdata": "[{\"studentid\":3,\"attemptid\":\"724\",\"tokenid\":\"dc049c8429af5ec2b8e7fe8a0b20d4a3\"}]",
    "quizid": "5",
    "tap": false,
    "body": "",
    "data": "[{\"question\":\"If a and b are negative numbers, and b - a is negative\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]},{\"question\":\"The equation 2x 7 \u003d 2(x 5) has one solution\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[false,true]},{\"question\":\"If f(x)\u003dsqrt(1-x), then f(-3)\u003d2\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]},{\"question\":\"The reciprocal of 0 is equal to 0\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[false,true]},{\"question\":\"The additive inverse of -10 is equal to 10\",\"options\":[\"True\",\"False\"],\"answer\":[true,false]}]",
    "title": "Quiz"
}
obj.studentdata = JSON.parse(obj.studentdata)
obj.data = JSON.parse(obj.data)
console.log("student data :", obj.studentdata)
console.log(" data :", obj.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply .. but i have data like that only.... How do i parse it

Comment: I have double quotes in between array subscript

Comment: one more question please...i want to retrive the data values from data array one by one ... how do i do that ?

Comment: @KumarK, looks like, you have to study fundamentals.okay I will point you a direction for how to looping over objects and arrays.  study and make it happen. so that you will understand better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Got It, Thank you